# How do I delete all DistListItems from a MAPIFolder?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I just encountered strange behavior from my VSTO Outlook add-in. I am trying to delete all distribution lists stored in an Outlook folder.

Here is how I do that:

```
public Outlook.MAPIFolder ListsFolder;

foreach (DistListItem distList in ListsFolder.Items.OfType<DistListItem>())
{
    distList.Delete();
}
```

It deletes a whole lot of lists, but strangely not all of them. A few always remain. As far as I can see, there's nothing special about those. All of the lists in this folder have been programmatically created by the same add-in, like this:

```
myList = ListsFolder.Items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olDistributionListItem) as Outlook.DistListItem;
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, never loop through all items in a folder - you wouldn't execute a SELECT SQL statement without a WHERE clause, would you? Use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` - let the store provider do the filtering. In your case, the search query would be `[MessageClass] = 'IPM.DistList'`.

Secondly, you are deleting items from a collection thus changing it - that is why some items are always skipped. You need to either use a down loop from Count to 1, or store all entry ids in a string list and then loop though that list opening each item using `Namespace.GetItemfromID`.